# Is it possible to have padding on a drawable that affects its intrinsic height?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to create a drawable XML file for a LinearLayout divider (see [here](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/11/17/grid-spacing-on-android/) if you are unfamiliar with LinearLayout dividers).

What I am after is a 1 dp line, with a 12dp top and bottom padding. This way, my items will be nicely spaced out and will have a line separator. The `<shape>` drawable does have padding, but this doesn't affect the height of the drawable itself, hence using that does nothing unless it is inflated into a view. Is there any way of doing this with Android's XML drawables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use the `<size>` child element of `<shape>`, as Cyril's blog post demonstrates?

Comment: I do, and it works as he says, but I want the divider to be 1dp in height + have the spacing on the top and bottom. If I set the height to 24dp, for example, the divider is now really thick (with no spacing on the top and bottom).

Comment: And if I set the height to 1dp, the divider is now correctly thin, but I can't achieve the padding on the top and bottom. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Note: when I say divider, I'm talking about a black line. When I talk about the padding, what I actually mean is margin. I want transparent space top and bottom. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I'd hope that the `<padding>` element would work for the padding/margin, though I have never tried it.